# Get form coordinates of a custom control

Tags: c#, graphics

In Winforms, I have implemented a custom object with a draw method, which is called by Form_Paint. I now want to be able to get the coordinates of this object after being drawn to the form, for the sake of a Move procedure in the works. I have tried using object.Location, object.Left, and object.Top, but these just give 0,0. I then tried object.Size to test, and it gave me the size of the form.

How can I get the location of my runtime object on the form? Thanks

Comment: Does anyone have suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
Point objLocation= cusObject.FindForm().PointToClient(
cusObject.Parent.PointToScreen(cusObject.Location));
```

Comment: That makes the form show a red X, definitely not what I wanted